# Remove line return in a string from the second "\n" and the rest (do not remove the first one)

Tags: r, regex, macos

I have sequences that I want to reformat in R.

But R presents me the sequences with returns of lines (as can be seen with the `"\n"`:

```
seqs <- ">PRTRE213-13 Volkameria aculeatum matK \n------------------------------------------------------------------CCAAC\nCGAGAGCCAGCTCC------TCTTTTTCAAAA---------CGAAAT---------------------CAA\nAAGACTATTCTTATTCTTATAT------------AATTCTCATGTATGTGAATATGAATCCGTTTTCGTCT\nTTTCTACGTAACCAATCTTTT---CATTTACGATCAACATCTTTTGAAGTTCTTCTTGAACGAATCTATTT\nTCTATGTA---------AAAGTAGAACGTCTT------GTGAACGTCTTTGTTAAGATTAAC---------\n-AATTTTCGGGCGAACCCGTGGTTGGTCAAG------GAACCTTTCATGCATTATATTAGGTATCAAAGAA\nAGATCCATTCTGGCTTCA------AAGGGAACATCTTTTTTCATGAAAAAATGGCAATTTTATCTTGTCAC\nCTTTTTGGCAATGGCATTTTTCGCTGTGGTTTCATCCAAGAAGGATTTATCTAAAC---CAATTATCCAAT\nTTATTCCCTTGAA------TTTTTGGGCTATCTTTCA------AGCGTGCGAATGAACCCCTCTGTGGTAC\nCGGAGTCAAATTCTAGAAAATGCATTTCTAATCAATAATGCTATT------AAGAAGTTTGATACCCTTAT\nTTCCAATTATTCCAATGATTGCGTCATTGGCTAAAGCGAAATTTTGTAACGTATTTGGGCATCCTGTTAGT\nTAAGCCGATTTGGGCTGATTTATCAGATTCTAATATTATTGACCGATTTGGTCGTATA---TGCAGAAATC\nCTTTCTC-------------"
```

But I want to remove all the `\n`*except* the first one. I.e.:

```
[1] ">PRTRE213-13 Volkameria aculeatum matK \n------------------------------------------------------------------CCAACCGAGAGCCAGCTCC------TCTTTTTCAAAA---------CGAAAT---------------------CAAAAGACTATTCTTATTCTTATAT------------AATTCTCATGTATGTGAATATGAATCCGTTTTCGTCTTTTCTACGTAACCAATCTTTT---CATTTACGATCAACATCTTTTGAAGTTCTTCTTGAACGAATCTATTTTCTATGTA---------AAAGTAGAACGTCTT------GTGAACGTCTTTGTTAAGATTAAC----------AATTTTCGGGCGAACCCGTGGTTGGTCAAG------GAACCTTTCATGCATTATATTAGGTATCAAAGAAAGATCCATTCTGGCTTCA------AAGGGAACATCTTTTTTCATGAAAAAATGGCAATTTTATCTTGTCACCTTTTTGGCAATGGCATTTTTCGCTGTGGTTTCATCCAAGAAGGATTTATCTAAAC---CAATTATCCAATTTATTCCCTTGAA------TTTTTGGGCTATCTTTCA------AGCGTGCGAATGAACCCCTCTGTGGTACCGGAGTCAAATTCTAGAAAATGCATTTCTAATCAATAATGCTATT------AAGAAGTTTGATACCCTTATTTCCAATTATTCCAATGATTGCGTCATTGGCTAAAGCGAAATTTTGTAACGTATTTGGGCATCCTGTTAGTTAAGCCGATTTGGGCTGATTTATCAGATTCTAATATTATTGACCGATTTGGTCGTATA---TGCAGAAATCCTTTCTC-------------"
```

If I do this, it removes all of the returns.

```
gsub(pattern = "\n",replacement = "", x = seqs)
```

This is not working:

```
sub("^(.*? \n .*?) \n .*", "\\1", seqs)
```

This gives me an error:

```
gsub(pattern = "${'\n'[*]:0:2}",replacement = "", x = seqs)
Error in gsub(pattern = "${'\n'[*]:0:2}", replacement = "", x = seqs) : 
  invalid regular expression '${'
'[*]:0:2}', reason 'Invalid contents of {}'
```

My sequences are variable:

```
">Whatever here before \n the sequence start \n the rest \n..."
```

The end result would be

```
">Whatever here before \n the sequence start the rest..."
```

Interestingly, the code below partially works for the test sentence, but not the sequence above:

```
seqss = ">Whatever here before \n the sequence start \n the rest \n..."
sub("^(.*? \n .*?) \n .*", "\\1", seqss)
[1] ">Whatever here before \n the sequence start"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
seqs <- ">PRTRE213-13 Volkameria aculeatum matK \n------------------------------------------------------------------CCAAC\nCGAGAGCCAGCTCC------TCTTTTTCAAAA---------CGAAAT---------------------CAA\nAAGACTATTCTTATTCTTATAT------------AATTCTCATGTATGTGAATATGAATCCGTTTTCGTCT\nTTTCTACGTAACCAATCTTTT---CATTTACGATCAACATCTTTTGAAGTTCTTCTTGAACGAATCTATTT\nTCTATGTA---------AAAGTAGAACGTCTT------GTGAACGTCTTTGTTAAGATTAAC---------\n-AATTTTCGGGCGAACCCGTGGTTGGTCAAG------GAACCTTTCATGCATTATATTAGGTATCAAAGAA\nAGATCCATTCTGGCTTCA------AAGGGAACATCTTTTTTCATGAAAAAATGGCAATTTTATCTTGTCAC\nCTTTTTGGCAATGGCATTTTTCGCTGTGGTTTCATCCAAGAAGGATTTATCTAAAC---CAATTATCCAAT\nTTATTCCCTTGAA------TTTTTGGGCTATCTTTCA------AGCGTGCGAATGAACCCCTCTGTGGTAC\nCGGAGTCAAATTCTAGAAAATGCATTTCTAATCAATAATGCTATT------AAGAAGTTTGATACCCTTAT\nTTCCAATTATTCCAATGATTGCGTCATTGGCTAAAGCGAAATTTTGTAACGTATTTGGGCATCCTGTTAGT\nTAAGCCGATTTGGGCTGATTTATCAGATTCTAATATTATTGACCGATTTGGTCGTATA---TGCAGAAATC\nCTTTCTC-------------"
gsub(pattern = "(^.*?\\n)|\\n",replacement = "\\1", x = seqs, perl = TRUE)
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Rbu3A/2)

The idea of the regex

```
(^.*?\\n)|\\n
```

is to capture everything up to the first newline in a group to retain and put it back in the replacement.

Comment: No additional packages whatsoever needed.

Comment: Note that (I think) this approach relies on the first group before the first newline having some distinguishing feature to prevent it also being replaced. here it is the leading `>`.

Comment: Actually if you change to this: `"(^.*?\\n)|\\n"` I think you can avoid this restriction

Comment: Thank you. The `^` was already present in the original R sample I gave but overlooked it when I copied over the explanatory regex line from the first version of the demo. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

A `stringr` approach that simply splits the string and combines the two parts back together.

```r
seqs <- ">PRTRE213-13 Volkameria aculeatum matK \n------------------------------------------------------------------CCAAC\nCGAGAGCCAGCTCC------TCTTTTTCAAAA---------CGAAAT---------------------CAA\nAAGACTATTCTTATTCTTATAT------------AATTCTCATGTATGTGAATATGAATCCGTTTTCGTCT\nTTTCTACGTAACCAATCTTTT---CATTTACGATCAACATCTTTTGAAGTTCTTCTTGAACGAATCTATTT\nTCTATGTA---------AAAGTAGAACGTCTT------GTGAACGTCTTTGTTAAGATTAAC---------\n-AATTTTCGGGCGAACCCGTGGTTGGTCAAG------GAACCTTTCATGCATTATATTAGGTATCAAAGAA\nAGATCCATTCTGGCTTCA------AAGGGAACATCTTTTTTCATGAAAAAATGGCAATTTTATCTTGTCAC\nCTTTTTGGCAATGGCATTTTTCGCTGTGGTTTCATCCAAGAAGGATTTATCTAAAC---CAATTATCCAAT\nTTATTCCCTTGAA------TTTTTGGGCTATCTTTCA------AGCGTGCGAATGAACCCCTCTGTGGTAC\nCGGAGTCAAATTCTAGAAAATGCATTTCTAATCAATAATGCTATT------AAGAAGTTTGATACCCTTAT\nTTCCAATTATTCCAATGATTGCGTCATTGGCTAAAGCGAAATTTTGTAACGTATTTGGGCATCCTGTTAGT\nTAAGCCGATTTGGGCTGATTTATCAGATTCTAATATTATTGACCGATTTGGTCGTATA---TGCAGAAATC\nCTTTCTC-------------"

library(stringr)

keep_first_newline <- function(string){
  first_newline <- str_locate(string, "\\n")[1]
  head <-  str_sub(string, end = first_newline)
  tail = string %>%
    str_sub(start = first_newline + 1) %>%
    str_remove_all("\\n")
  out <- str_c(head, tail)
}

seqs %>%
  keep_first_newline %>%
  writeLines
#> >PRTRE213-13 Volkameria aculeatum matK 
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------CCAACCGAGAGCCAGCTCC------TCTTTTTCAAAA---------CGAAAT---------------------CAAAAGACTATTCTTATTCTTATAT------------AATTCTCATGTATGTGAATATGAATCCGTTTTCGTCTTTTCTACGTAACCAATCTTTT---CATTTACGATCAACATCTTTTGAAGTTCTTCTTGAACGAATCTATTTTCTATGTA---------AAAGTAGAACGTCTT------GTGAACGTCTTTGTTAAGATTAAC----------AATTTTCGGGCGAACCCGTGGTTGGTCAAG------GAACCTTTCATGCATTATATTAGGTATCAAAGAAAGATCCATTCTGGCTTCA------AAGGGAACATCTTTTTTCATGAAAAAATGGCAATTTTATCTTGTCACCTTTTTGGCAATGGCATTTTTCGCTGTGGTTTCATCCAAGAAGGATTTATCTAAAC---CAATTATCCAATTTATTCCCTTGAA------TTTTTGGGCTATCTTTCA------AGCGTGCGAATGAACCCCTCTGTGGTACCGGAGTCAAATTCTAGAAAATGCATTTCTAATCAATAATGCTATT------AAGAAGTTTGATACCCTTATTTCCAATTATTCCAATGATTGCGTCATTGGCTAAAGCGAAATTTTGTAACGTATTTGGGCATCCTGTTAGTTAAGCCGATTTGGGCTGATTTATCAGATTCTAATATTATTGACCGATTTGGTCGTATA---TGCAGAAATCCTTTCTC-------------
```

Created on 2018-06-29 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Using `gsubfn` we can do. Not any better than the regex in this case, but more easily extended if you want to keep the first `n` occurrences with `n>1`.

```
library(gsubfn)
p <- proto(fun = function(this, x) if(count > 1) '' else x)
out <- gsubfn('\n', p, seqs)
```

Same as accepted answer

```
out == gsub(pattern = "(^.*?\\n)|\\n",replacement = "\\1", x = seqs, perl = TRUE)
#[1] TRUE
```